# tabs system for divs

Tags: html, tabs

Is there a way to have vertical tabs and use divs and not li?

```
    <div title="First Tab">
        <p>1 Tab</P>
    </div>
    <div title="Second Tab">
        <p>2 Tab</P>
    </div>
    <div title="Third Tab">
        <p>3 Tab</P>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
    <p style="text-indent:10px">This.</p>
</div>
<div>
    <p style="text-indent:10px">That.</p>
</div>
```

It's just some simple css.